# Query moongoDB from a redis list

Tags: mongodb, redis

If for example I keep lists of user posts in redis, for example a user has 1000 posts, and the posts documents are stored into mongodb but the link between the user and the posts is stored inside redis, I can rtetrieve the array containing all the ids of a user post from redis, but what is the efficient way to retrieving them from mongodb?

do I pass a parameter to mongoDB with the array of ids, and mongo will fetch those for me?

I don't seem to find any documentation on this, if Anyone is willing to help me out!

thanks in advance!

Comment: Why would you like to manage two sides of a relationship in two different databases? You should choose either Redis or mongoDB.

Comment: because mongoDb does not have the relational part of mysql.
Some parts of my project need the document architecture of mongo, and another part needs the relational part of mysql, so what I am doing, is, storing all the relational data in the form of redis lists with ids, and the true data is stored inside mongo db documents.

this way I can for example, do a diff on two lists and things like that, and still have the efficiency of noSql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve a number of documents per id, you can use the $in operator to build the MongoDB query. See the following section from the documentation:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in

For instance you can build a query such as:

```
db.mycollection.find( { _id : { $in: [ id1, id2, id3, .... ] } } )
```

Depending on how much ids will be returned by Redis, you may have to group them in batch of n items (n=100 for instance) to run several MongoDB queries. IMO, this is a bad practice to build such query containing more than a few thousands ids. It is better to have smaller queries but accept to pay for the extra roundtrips.

Comment: thanks alot for your answer, so that's how I am going to proceed, that's nice :), i've read alot of articles about using mongodb with redis for the relational part, but none explains how the queries work.

as for the round trips, I am ready to pay the price as long as the query time is constant.

thanks alot Didier!